# How to fix Read-only file system when running cordova run android?

Tags: cordova, android-studio, ubuntu, gradle, chmod

I am trying to execute

```sh
cordova run android --verbose
```

and I get

```sh
spawn EACCES
```

as an error.

So, I searched online and ran

```sh
cordova run android --verbose
```

and identified the error to be:

```sh
Running command: /snap/android-studio/76/android-studio/gradle/gradle-5.1.1/bin/gradle -p /home/extensify/Desktop/Code/cordova/platforms/android wrapper -b /home/extensify/Desktop/Code/cordova/platforms/android/wrapper.gradle
spawn EACCES
Error: spawn EACCES
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:502:9)
    at Function.spawn (/home/extensify/Desktop/Code/cordova/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js:12:24)
    at exports.spawn (/home/extensify/Desktop/Code/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:90:28)
    at ProjectBuilder.runGradleWrapper (/home/extensify/Desktop/Code/cordova/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/ProjectBuilder.js:70:20)
    at /home/extensify/Desktop/Code/cordova/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/ProjectBuilder.js:209:29
    at _fulfilled (/home/extensify/Desktop/Code/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/extensify/Desktop/Code/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/extensify/Desktop/Code/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
```

Which I read can be fixable by changing permissions for the file `/snap/android-studio/76/android-studio/gradle/gradle-5.1.1/bin/gradle`

To fix this I tried running

```sh
sudo chmod +x /snap/android-studio/76/android-studio/gradle/gradle-5.1.1/bin/gradle
```

and kept getting

```sh
chmod: changing permissions of '/snap/android-studio/76/android-studio/gradle/gradle-5.1.1/bin/gradle': Read-only file system
```

Which I read can be fixed by remounting my hard drive, which again I tried using several commands, but could not be fixed.

What can I try next?

Comment: which file-system does that partition have? because the file-system likely causes it to mount R/O... this barely is programming related, but might counts as a "general computing hardware and software" question, which is off-topic on here. and you can try much, unless you'd a) unmount the partition, b) fix the file-system and c) mount it R/W (which all has little to do with programming).

Comment: `cat /etc/fstab` or `sudo blkid` would at least tell the type of file-system... where each type has it's own tools to fix corruption, which all only operate on unmounted partitions.

Comment: `/dev/loop21: TYPE="squashfs"`
so you are saying I should find a tool that can unmount `/dev/loop21` and change the partition to be able to create and write?

Comment: [SquashFS](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SquashFS-HOWTO/whatis.html) cannot be fixed, it's compressed and it is read only. maybe just install cordova with `npm` and remove that crappy snap. can you create files in mount-point `/home` (just to be certain not that is mounted R/O, while it shouldn't)?

Comment: I did install cordova with `npm`, but the file I want to change permissions for is `gradle` which comes with `android-studio` that I installed with `snap`

Comment: I am going for uninstall `android-studio` and re-install using their website. Will tell you how it works tomorrow.

Comment: this will most likely work out. just extract the files somewhere where you have R/W access.

Comment: I wrote and answer on how to do this. There are some more steps to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is for Ubuntu 18.04

I had this same problem and here's how I fixed them:

1. Remove Android Studio if you installed it using snap.
2. [Download Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads) from their website
3. Extract to `/usr/local/` for your user profile, or `/opt/` for shared users
4. If you are using a 64-bit machine, run this command to install some required 32-bit packages:

```sh
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
```

5. Install KVM, add yourself to group `kvm`
6. Open a terminal, navigate to the `android-studio/bin/` directory, and execute `./studio.sh`
7. Run through the installation and make sure you install API Level 28 (Android 9.0 Pie) in SDK Platform
8. Add the following directories to `$PATH`:

   - `/opt/android-studio/gradle/gradle-{version}/bin` or `/usr/local/android-studio/gradle/gradle-{version}/bin`
   - `/opt/android-studio/jre/bin` or `/usr/local/android-studio/jre/bin`
   - `/home/{name}/Android/Sdk/platform-tools`
   - `/home/{name}/Android/Sdk/tools/bin`
   - `/home/{name}/Android/Sdk/emulator/bin`
9. Create a virtual device using Android Studio
10. List virtual devices using `android list avd`
11. Start a virtual device using `emulator -avd {deviceName}`
12. Run `cordova run android`, it should work

Recommended:

- Run Android Studio, go to `Tools > Create Desktop Entry...` so that you can launch Android Studio easily